# Kafka Streams reports "Global thread has died. The streams application or client will now close to ERROR" on shutdown

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Versions we use:
kafka-streams 3.4.1
spring-kafka 3.0.13
spring-boot 3.1.8

When we shutdown our Spring Boot application, we always receive this error log:
`stream-client [x] Global thread has died. The streams application or client will now close to ERROR.`

But I think we already shutdown kafka streams correctly:

```kotlin
@Bean
fun kafkaStreams(topology: Topology): KafkaStreams {
    [...]
    return KafkaStreams(topology, props).also { kafkaStreams ->
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(Thread { kafkaStreams.close() })
    }
}
```

I've also realized that in `org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.StreamStateListener#onChange`, there is a check on `state != State.PENDING_SHUTDOWN`, but I'm not sure if `state` was already set to `newState` in `org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams#setState`?

So, I'm not sure if we made a mistake somewhere in our shutdown procedure or if there is a bug in KafkaStreams...

Comment: Could you reproduce it on some sample project and push code to the GitHub public repository?

Comment: Maybe file a bug report: https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/